# How can I get weekly sales for every salesman

Tags: postgresql, left-join, coalesce

I have a table like below (tablename: sales)

| sales_datetime | sales | salesman |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 09:00:00 | 100 | John |
| 2022-08-01 11:00:00 | 200 | John |
| 2022-08-02 10:00:00 | 100 | Peter |
| 2022-08-02 13:00:00 | 300 | John |
| 2022-08-04 14:00:00 | 300 | Peter |
| 2022-08-05 12:00:00 | 100 | John |
| 2022-08-05 16:00:00 | 200 | John |

From that table I want to make a summary sales for 5 days period for each salesman. So the summary table that I want is look like this

| periode | total_sales | salesman |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 300 | John |
| 2022-08-01 | 0 | Peter |
| 2022-08-02 | 300 | John |
| 2022-08-02 | 100 | Peter |
| 2022-08-03 | 0 | John |
| 2022-08-03 | 0 | Peter |
| 2022-08-04 | 0 | John |
| 2022-08-04 | 300 | Peter |
| 2022-08-05 | 300 | John |
| 2022-08-05 | 0 | Peter |

I have created following query (PSQL) but the results were not same as I want. Assume today is 2022-08-05

```
with dateseries as 
(select generate_series(current_date-'4 days'::interval,
   current_date::date,
   '1 day'::interval)::date as periode)
select d.periode,coalesce(sum(s.sales),0) as total_sales,s.salesman from dateseries d
left outer join sales s
on d.periode=s.sales_datetime::date
group by d.periode, s.salesman order by d.periode
```

results:

| periode | total_sales | salesman |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 300 | John |
| 2022-08-02 | 300 | John |
| 2022-08-02 | 100 | Peter |
| 2022-08-03 | 0 | (NULL) |
| 2022-08-04 | 300 | Peter |
| 2022-08-05 | 300 | John |

Any advices would be so great. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step first aggregate the daily sales per salesperson (`aggregated_sales` CTE), create a list of days to report (`days` CTE), create a list of salesmen (`salesmen` CTE) and then query the sales for each day/salesman pair.

```sql
with aggregated_sales as 
(
 select sales_datetime::date sales_date, sum(sales) sales, salesman 
 from sales group by sales_datetime::date, salesman
),
days(sales_date) as 
(
 select d::date 
 from generate_series('2022-08-01', '2022-08-08', interval '1 day') d
),
salesmen (salesman) as 
(
 select distinct salesman from sales
)
select sales_date, coalesce(sales, 0) sales, salesman 
from (select * from days cross join salesmen) fl 
left outer join aggregated_sales ags using (sales_date, salesman);
```

The query may be shorter if CTEs are inlined yet I think that clarity and readability are more important than mere size.

In order to "make a summary sales for 5 days period for each salesman" replace `generate_series('2022-08-01', '2022-08-08', interval '1 day')` with `generate_series(current_date - 4, current_date, interval '1 day')`.

Comment: Thank you @Stefanov.sm. I like the 'cross join' idea !

Answer (score 0):

> the results were not same as I want. Assume today is 2022-08-05

Please note that `'2022-08-05'::date - '5 days'::interval` will give you `2022-07-31`, and not `2022-08-01` as you assume. Because of that, I think you meant it to be `current_date - '4 days'::interval`.

With that out of the way, here is one possible query:

```
with sales_by_date as (
    select
        salesman,
        sales_datetime::date,
        sum(sales) total_sales
    from sales
    where 
    -- assuming you need to have totals for salesmen that had sales in specified period only
        sales_datetime::date between current_date-'4 days'::interval and current_date 
    group by
        salesman,
        sales_datetime::date),
dateseries as (
    select
        distinct salesman,
        generate_series(current_date-'4 days'::interval, current_date, '1 day'::interval)::date as periode
    from sales_by_date)
select
    d.periode,
    coalesce(s.total_sales, 0) total_sales,
    d.salesman
from dateseries d
left join sales_by_date s 
 on d.periode = s.sales_datetime
and d.salesman = s.salesman
order by d.periode, d.salesman;
```

But you still have to figure out some requirements for this problem. E.g. what if for the specified period there are no sales at all in the `sales` table?